# CodeIgniter making the date helper output 12 hour format

Tags: codeigniter

Using the Ci date helper, how would I turn '06/08/2012 17:10pm' into 12 hour format?

```
date('m/d/Y H:ia ', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code has nothing to do with CodeIgniter, it's simply PHP functions. For information on the date function, see the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

The small chatacter `h` puts the hour in 12-hour format and capital chatacter `H` puts the hour in 24-hour format.

Change the code to this:

```
date('m/d/Y h:ia ', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime))
```